# efficiently showing the user only items he did not already see before (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

This question applies to any kind of system that contains items (e.g: news articles) and users that watch these items.

So let's say i have a users table `([id],[username])`, an articles table `([id],[title],[text])` and a table that contains all the articles viewed by all the users `([user_id],[article_id])`.

What i want to do is efficiently show the user only the articles he did not already read before.

I know i can just do something like

```
select id,title,text from articles where id not in (select article_id
from article_views where user_id = 123)
```

But what if the current user already read 1M articles ?  the query will become something like

```
select id,... from articles where id not in (1,2,3,......1000000)
```

This, i can assume, is too slow to be practical.

Also, it sucks because the more articles a user reads - the slower response time he will have retrieving new (unread) articles..

Any other suggestions, db-wise ?

Comment: Your query is not too slow. Assuming appropriate indexes the database will rewrite that as a join.  @Yuck had the correct answer but for some reason deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, by doing a LEFT JOIN and only returning NULL (ie: not found) entries might be faster than sub-select.  It's does a direct join A:B and only includes those where NO match is found

```
select
      a.id,
      a.title,
      a.text 
   from 
      articles a
         LEFT JOIN article_views av
            on av.User_ID = 123
           AND a.id = av.article_id
   where
      av.article_id IS NULL
```

I would ensure an index on ( UserID, Article_ID ) (which I believe would be your primary key to that table anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding them directly in to the statement, you could run something like:

```
select articles.id, ... from articles, article_views where article_views.user_id = [useridhere] and articles.id != article_views.id
```

It alleviates the issue with having huge queries, but you're still comparing a million articles if you have a million articles.

Comment: thanks for the answer,but i cannot accept your answer since it did not solve the efficiency problem ..